# Error when calling flickrapi.photosets.getPhotos method

Tags: python, flickr

I am trying to use [flickrapi](http://stuvel.eu/flickrapi) from @sybren on python 3.4. 
Therefore i cloned the main branch of the repo and installed the package.
Some function calls do work, but some give me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\personal works\flickrWorks\flickr_derpage.py", line 20, in <module>
    flickr.photosets.getPhotos(set_id)
TypeError: __call__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

The call to the function is this one:

```
import flickrapi
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# config stuff
api_key = 'fuhsdkjfsdjkfsjk'
api_secret = 'fdjksnfkjsdnfkj'
user_tbp_dev = "fednkjfnsdjkfnjksdn5"

# le program
flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, api_secret)
sets = flickr.photosets.getList(user_id=user_tbp_dev)
set0 = sets.find('photosets').findall('photoset')
set_id = set0[0].get('id')

sett_photos = flickr.photosets.getPhotos(set_id)
print(ET.dump(sett_photos))
```

Another method which gives the same error is:

```
flickr.reflection.getMethodInfo("flickr.photos.search")
```

Any ideas what might i do wrong, or if the library has some issues (as the python3 branch is still under development).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flickrapi expects the parameters to the functions to be named arguments, not positional.  This works for me:
flickr.photosets_getPhotos(photoset_id=set_id, extras="license, date_upload, date_taken")

To get a list of the argument names for the Flickr calls, see the documentation here: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.getPhotos.html

Comment: Thanks, it works! (and sorry for the late answer, you know, holidays  and stuffs :D). What's interesting is that for some api calls, there was no need to name the arguments. Oh well, thanks again!